# Retrieve all lists and libraries in a sharepoint online site using c# console application

Tags: c#, list, sharepoint, console-application, sharepoint-online

Is there any way to retrieve all the lists and libraries in a sharepoint online site?

I tried using c# console application.

Can suggest/explain a code to make this work?
I just need basically to connect to sharepoint online site and retrieve all the lists and libraries.

Comment: [Get to know the SharePoint REST service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-to-know-the-sharepoint-rest-service?tabs=csom) gl

Answer (score 1):

I tried this code and it became handy for me

```
private static void GetAllLists(ICredentials credentials, string weburl)  
{  
    using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(weburl))  
    {  
        ctx.Credentials = credentials;  
        Web oweb = ctx.Web;  
        ListCollection lists = oweb.Lists;  
        ctx.Load(lists);  
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();  
        Console.WriteLine("All Lists / Libraries: " + lists.Count().ToString());  
        foreach (List lst in lists)  
        {  
            Console.WriteLine(lst.Title);  
        }  
    }  
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");  
    Console.Read();  
}
```

I hope it become handy for you too !

Answer (score 0):

This forum is very informative, you can use this site as a reference

https://www.codesharepoint.com/csom/9/file

[image]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34942690)